# How to use the key values of a prolog dict in a predicate?

Tags: json, dictionary, attributes, prolog

I have a simple question which I'm getting a lot of trouble finding an answer.

I'm building an api that reads json and at the moment it successfully converts the json to a dict with http_read_json_dict. The problem is that, I have no clue how to access the attributes inside the dict and use that that data in a predicate. 
 I tried following the `swi-prolog` documentation but to no avail... Do you guys know of a way?

I tried this to test read the content of the dict but I get a `"key_value expected, found a dict"` error. Please don't burn me at the stake:

json contains: `[{"task":"learnprolog","dayofmonth":2}]`

```
  http_read_json_dict(Request, JSONIn,[json_object(term)]),
  X = JSONIn,
  format(user_output,"task is: ~p~n",[X.task]),
  JSONOut=JSONIn.
```

But i was really hoping to do something like:

`predicate(X):- X.dayofmonth==2,doSomething(X.task);doSomethingElse(X.task)`.

Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 1):

not sure about the details, without a server setup similar to what you're using... but

```
?- open_codes_stream(`[{"task":"learnprolog","dayofmonth":"2"}]`,S),json_read_dict(S,[J]),close(S),write(J.dayofmonth).
2
S = <stream>(0x7f5f14304dd0),
J = _G15591{dayofmonth:"2", task:"learnprolog"}.
```

note the square brackets around **J**

Comment: Hi. thanks for the answer. I get the feeling that the stream is important, but how do I use the JSONIn variable as an argument of open_codes_stream instead of hardcoding the JSON in there?

Comment: sorry, I was not suggesting to use open_codes_stream... was just an example to get actual JSON from (known) text. Maybe I don't really understand your problem... JSONIn **should** already be a dict, so... what's the point ?

Comment: yea it is a dict...but the problem is that if i try to do X = JSONIn.task i get an error "key_value expected, found a dict".

Comment: seems that **task** is a dict... maybe all would be clear is you could writeln(JSONIn)...

Comment: yes it is a dict... o_o the http_read_json_dict stored each of the attributes as dicts and not as 1 single dict with 2 attributes because i used [{"task":"learnprolog","dayofmonth":2}] instead of {"task":"learnprolog","dayofmonth":2}....god...thanks for helping me clarify that...